# Adding S3 trigger to Lambda function using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to add an S3 trigger to a lambda function using CloudFormation. From what I've read about circular references the lambda function and S3 bucket needs to be created first, which I've done with a template and they get created successfully.

Then I go into "Update Stack" and enter the template:

```
 "Resources": {
        "MyBucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "NotificationConfiguration": {
                "LambdaConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                        "Function": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:newlyCreatedLambda"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName": "MyBucket"
....
....
```

But when I try to deploy it gives the error:

```
Template is not valid: Invalid template resource property 'NotificationConfiguration'
```

Any idea how to get the trigger added or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `NotificationConfiguration` should be a key in the `Properties` dictionary

Comment: Thanks @yorodm! Missed that :)

Comment: I created a related question here as the update is failing for a different reason:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995003/error-updating-stack-to-add-s3-trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what we use:

```
"BucketForFunctionsAcesImportNewFileUploaded": {
  "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
  "Properties": {
    "NotificationConfiguration": {
      "TopicConfigurations": [],
      "QueueConfigurations": [],
      "LambdaConfigurations": [
        {
          "Function": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "FunctionsAcesImportNewFileUploaded",
              "Arn"
            ]
          },
          "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
        }
      ]
    },
    "VersioningConfiguration": {
      "Status": "Suspended"
    }
  },
  "DeletionPolicy": "Delete"
}
```

Comment: Where do you create the S3 bucket in this case?
And do you have a YAML version of this by any chance?

Comment: This is the definition for the bucket...  "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket".  No, no YAML, sorry

Answer (score -2):

To add an S3 trigger to a Lambda function using AWS CloudFormation, you need to define the necessary resources and permissions in a CloudFormation template. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do this:

Create an S3 Bucket (if you haven't already):
You'll need an S3 bucket to trigger your Lambda function. You can create one in your CloudFormation template or use an existing one.

To create an S3 bucket in your CloudFormation template, you can use the AWS::S3::Bucket resource type.

Example:

yaml code
MyS3Bucket:
Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
Create an IAM Role for Lambda:
Your Lambda function will need permission to access the S3 bucket. Create an IAM role with the necessary permissions for your Lambda function.

Example:

yaml code
LambdaExecutionRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
RoleName: MyLambdaRole
AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
Version: "2012-10-17"
Statement:
- Effect: Allow
Principal:
Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
Action: sts:AssumeRole
Policies:
- PolicyName: S3AccessPolicy
PolicyDocument:
Version: "2012-10-17"
Statement:
- Effect: Allow
Action:
- s3:GetObject
Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::MyS3Bucket/*"
Create the Lambda Function:
Define your Lambda function in the CloudFormation template, specifying the S3 bucket as an event trigger.

Example:

yaml code
MyLambdaFunction:
Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
Properties:
FunctionName: MyS3TriggeredLambda
Handler: index.handler
Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
Code:
S3Bucket: my-lambda-deployment-bucket
S3Key: my-lambda-deployment-package.zip
Runtime: nodejs14.x
Timeout: 30
Events:
S3Event:
Type: S3
Properties:
Bucket: !Ref MyS3Bucket
Events:
- s3:ObjectCreated:*
Create the Lambda Permission for S3:
You need to add permissions to allow the S3 bucket to invoke the Lambda function. Use the AWS::Lambda::Permission resource for this.

Example:

yaml code
LambdaPermissionForS3:
Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
Properties:
FunctionName: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::MyS3Bucket"
Deploy the CloudFormation Stack:
Deploy the CloudFormation stack using the AWS Management Console, AWS CLI, or AWS SDKs.

Once you've created the CloudFormation stack, it will create the S3 bucket, IAM role, Lambda function, and the necessary permissions. The Lambda function will be triggered whenever a new object is created in the specified S3 bucket.

Make sure to adapt the template to your specific requirements, including the bucket name, Lambda function code, and any other configuration parameters.