# add S3 trigger on a Lambda function with cloudformation yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

So I have this issue that I would love to:

1. Create an S3-bucket
2. Add this S3 bucket as a trigger to the current lambda function I'm using.

This is something which has to be done in YAML

I have no clue how to set this up...
What I've managed to so far, is to create an s3 bucket which worked perfectly, now I just need to attach it as a trigger to the lambda function.

It's pretty easy to set up in the AWS console but I just don't have much experience with YAML. So I have no idea how to set this up correctly, and the file is really sensitive so Its a pain in the ass :-).

- Runtime: node.js 10.x

Wished end result with yaml:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991413/adding-s3-trigger-to-lambda-function-using-cloudformation

Comment: so convert from JSON to YAML? https://www.json2yaml.com/

Comment: If you are still not able to make it, let me know. I will build an example and post it

Comment: Thanks didn't know that.. I could try... But im still missing the part for to create the s3-bucket Don't think its included in the answer... Unless I misunderstand something.

Comment: I do know how to convert it from JSOn to YAML but as mentioned Im not sure what 
FunctionsAcesImportNewFileUploaded is and where the s3 bucket is being created etc...
And example would be appreciated.

Comment: ok let i post an example then

Comment: You might also want to investigate the serverless framework. Here's an example project that uses a Node Lambda function, triggered by S3 object creation: https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-simple-transcribe-s3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have built a small template , tested.

The template are to

- Create S3 bucket. It is trigger Lambda with all file ends with txt.
  If you don't want any Filter, please remove Filter from the template
- Create Permission, so S3 can trigger Lambda function. (Note: I just
  fake name, please change accordingly)
- Create a Lambda (Note: I'm using an existing role arn:aws:iam::057351434671:role/lambda_sqs but you can create or use another role from your organization )

YML version

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: This template is to create all resources for Config Service Api
Parameters:
  LambdaArtifactBucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: befit-artifact
  S3BucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: befit-test-s3
Resources:
  ExampleS3:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: ExampleInvokePermission
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref S3BucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: suffix
                    Value: txt
            Function: !GetAtt [ ExampleLambdaFunction, Arn]
  ExampleInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    DependsOn: ExampleLambdaFunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - ExampleLambdaFunction
          - Arn
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:
        Fn::Sub: arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketName}
  ExampleLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: LambdaArtifactBucketName
        S3Key: emailnotification-1.0.0.jar
      FunctionName: example-lambda-function
      Handler: com.xxx.Example::handleRequest
      Role: arn:aws:iam::057351434671:role/lambda_sqs
      Runtime: java8
      Timeout: '300'
      MemorySize: 512

Outputs:
  S3BucketSecureURL:
    Value: !Join ['', ['https://', !GetAtt [ExampleS3, DomainName]]]
    Description: Name of S3 bucket
```

Json version

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
   "Description": "This template is to create all resources for Config Service Api",
   "Parameters": {
      "LambdaArtifactBucketName": {
         "Type": "String",
         "Default": "befit-artifact"
      },
      "S3BucketName": {
         "Type": "String",
         "Default": "befit-test-s3"
      }
   },
   "Resources": {
      "ExampleS3": {
         "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
         "DependsOn": "ExampleInvokePermission",
         "Properties": {
            "BucketName": null,
            "NotificationConfiguration": {
               "LambdaConfigurations": [
                  {
                     "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
                     "Filter": {
                        "S3Key": {
                           "Rules": [
                              {
                                 "Name": "suffix",
                                 "Value": "txt"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     "Function": null
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "ExampleInvokePermission": {
         "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
         "DependsOn": "ExampleLambdaFunction",
         "Properties": {
            "FunctionName": {
               "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "ExampleLambdaFunction",
                  "Arn"
               ]
            },
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
            "SourceArn": {
               "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketName}"
            }
         }
      },
      "ExampleLambdaFunction": {
         "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
         "Properties": {
            "Code": {
               "S3Bucket": {
                  "Ref": "LambdaArtifactBucketName"
               },
               "S3Key": "emailnotification-1.0.0.jar"
            },
            "FunctionName": "example-lambda-function",
            "Handler": "com.xxx.Example::handleRequest",
            "Role": "arn:aws:iam::057351434671:role/lambda_sqs",
            "Runtime": "java8",
            "Timeout": "300",
            "MemorySize": 512
         }
      }
   },
   "Outputs": {
      "S3BucketSecureURL": {
         "Value": null,
         "Description": "Name of S3 bucket"
      }
   }
}
```

After the template ran, the output will be
[image]
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Sure. Anytime . Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I've tried to get it together but with no luck...
I am using Node.js 10.x 
Not sure if this will make any difference to your answer?
Could you please tell me how the
 Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: LambdaArtifactBucketName
        S3Key: emailnotification-1.0.0.jar
works? In my stack event I can see that I get the error: NoSuchBucket And that I need to give a value for S3Bucket and S3Key? In the ExampleLambdaFunction

Comment: StrawHat, you need to give correct bucket and key for your lambda execution.

Comment: The CF is created the S3 bucket