# How to add a object notication event trigger to a serveless lamda in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I am creating a lambda function (serverless) via cloudformation , see template below . in my aws account there are s3 buckets which were created manually and i can't add or change them. so can i add , s3 object notification trigger in my lambda? if so, i want to trigger this event, only for files under certain prefix/folder and for certain extensions . how can i achieve this ? do i need s3 bucket name or arn for this ?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.9
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      code:
      ....
      Tags:
        - Key: Lambda
          Value: MyLambdaFunction
      ...
  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: policy..
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 's3:*'
                Resource: '*'
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167514/add-s3-trigger-on-a-lambda-function-with-cloudformation-yaml

Answer (score 1):

You can set trigger but you need to use AWS::Serverless::Function instead of AWS::Lambda::Function.

In AWS::Lambda::Function it is not possible.

and configure events into the AWS::Serverless::Function properties

```
Events:
  S3Event:
    Type: S3
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: ImagesBucket     
      Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
      Filter:
        S3Key:
          Rules:
          - Name: prefix      # or "suffix"
            Value: value      # The value to search for in the S3 object key names
```

You can refer this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-resource-function-syntax)

If you want to know what is the difference between lambda function and serverless function please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953270/what-is-the-difference-between-a-serverless-function-and-a-lambda-function)

You can import your existing s3 bucket to cloudformation as well. aws provide resource import option as well.